# Bluetooth doesn't set high fidelity, don't have an `audio.conf` file

Tags: sound, bluetooth

My Bluetooth headphones initially connect with a poor (almost unintelligible) sound quality, and when I click on the settings and click to set it to high fidelity, there's no save button to lock the setting in and the audio quality stays bad even if I click the option and close the settings panel.  Besides this it would be nice if they auto-connected at high fidelity.  I've see other guides suggest editing `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`.  I have the directory `/etc/bluetooth/` but the only files in it are input, main, network, and proximity.  I added `AutoConnect=true` to the end of the main.conf file since this seemed to be approximately what other people suggested doing, but didn't fix my problem.  Any other ideas?